# replacing elements of a string in C

Tags: c, string

The Spinx brothers have planted a bomb in Tokyo’s Metropolitan Police Headquarters. Quite
conveniently, they left behind a string S (encrypted, of course) as the key to defuse the bomb, but
there is more to it.
The police from their previous encounters with the Sphinx brothers have deduced a possible
decryption. Some of the letters in the string need to be replaced with some other letter in accordance
with the decryption pattern. It is possible that a decrypted letter can be decrypted/replaced again.
You need to replace each letter in the string until it cannot further be replaced, to obtain the key.
They challenge you to do this as quickly as possible, as the bomb in the headquarters is about to
explode any time now.

**Input**

The first line has the string S (1 ≤ |S| ≤ 105) consisting of lowercase letters only. The next line has a
single integer M (1 ≤ M ≤ 325), denoting the number of replacements. The next M lines have two
spaced characters, ci and di, with di being the replacement of ci.

**Output**

Print the final string after all character replacements.

**Note**

It is guaranteed that there are no cyclic replacements.

**input**

```
nineandeleven

5

n l

l u

u w

e a

a y
```

**output**

```
wiwyywdywyvyw
```

**This is how I coded it. I couldn't take more than 3 rows of inputs**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char str[100000];
    scanf("%s",str);
    int M;
    char x,y;
    scanf("%d",&M);


    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        scanf("%c %c",&x,&y);
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(str);j++){
            if(str[j] == x) { str[j]=y;}
        }
    }

    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework problem! Please try & state where you have gone wrong.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the first for loop as I told earlier that I am not able to take more than 3 rows of input.  Any insights would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c %c",&x,&y);
```

change to

```
scanf(" %c %c",&x,&y);
```

one more space

because when you enter "enter"

will push newline(windows.linux may be little different like `\t\n` `\n` if you want to know google it) to your buffer

when you use `%c` will read last you push not jump space, `'\n'`, `'\t'`

when you add space in front of `%c`

`scanf` will jump space, `'\n'`, `'\t'` before read buffer then will get correct your input by your keyboard

Answer (score -1):

maybe its a bug i didnt it like that before seems you increment the index in the first %c scanf
there is a solution u can use strtok(str, delimiter) in string.h each time scan the whole string like "l p" then split it with the white spase

```
char d[3];
scanf("%s", d);
x = s[0];
y = s[2];
```

then increment your index etc..

or split it

```
char *token;
char d[3];
scanf("%s", d);
token = strtok(d, ' ');
x = token[0];
y = token[1];
```

Good Luck

Comment: Though about buffer overflow

Comment: Using `strtok` on string with max size of 2 characters (buffer size 3) seems... not useful.